# Dynamic options within a select field with react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to solve the next task with ReactJS: let's assume I have several questions and answer fields. I would like to make it possible to distribute 10 points between all answers on the page.

I made a form that included several `<select>` fields that are being dynamically populated with `<option>` tags depending on current user input state.

The problem is that when user selects values, they are being reseted to zero again. 
Please see a code example here and try to select some values:
https://jsfiddle.net/jcpyqf9v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by populating the options of your Select, here:

```
let optionNodes = [];
for (let k = 0; k < 11 - pointsSum; k++) {
  optionNodes.push(<option key={k} value={k}>{k}</option>);
}
```

Because you're only outputing a subset of the options, if the option selected isn't on the list, the select field has no choice but to output the default; `0`.

Try this instead;

```
let optionNodes = [];
for (let k = 0; k < 11 - pointsSum || k <= this.state.answers[i]; k++) {
  optionNodes.push(<option key={k} value={k}>{k}</option>);
}
```

Comment: You got to the root of it. I thought the problem was connected somehow to React and dug in wrong direction. Thanks!